number of lifts of a representation of a finite group to a central extension
Let $G$ be a finite group, and $H\rightarrow G$ a central extension. I'm happy to assume $G$ perfect, or even that it be nonabelian simple.
I'd like to understand the relationship between the representation theory of $G$ and that of $H$. For example, suppose that the center $Z(H)$ of $H$ is cyclic of prime order. Then certain sources seem to claim that for a faithful character $\chi : Z(H)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^\times$, the number of irreducible characters of $H$ whose restriction to $Z(H)$ is $\chi$ is independent of the choice of the faithful character $\chi$. Is this true? How does this follow from Clifford theory? (if it does)

Aren’t all faithfully characters of a cyclic group of prime order Galois-conjugate?
